# How to run database functions in the background?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I am working on C# windows forms and have come across this problem

I have two forms and in first form user enters username and press button. Button calls a function that saves username in database.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    db.SaveUsername(txtUsername.Text);
    new Form2().Show();
}
```

and this `SaveUsername()` function is in separate class

```
class Database
{
    public void SaveUsername(string username)
    {
        Connect(); //Connection to database
        //Some lines to save username in database
    }
}
```

My problem is when user hits enter it takes a bit time to open `Form2` so I want that new form should come up and `SaveUsername()` function runs in background without having user to wait for it to complete. How is it done?

Comment: have you heard about `Async` methods?

Comment: Hey! No. I am learning C# . New to it

Comment: @Allen you may also want to read up on how to overload methods of the other form for the constructor of the second form, and what to pass to the other form when creating an instance of that 2nd form, along with Async methods which just to write to a database for a user / password doesn't not make sense to use this approach for a simple insert. it would also help to see as well as know a bit more about your current architecture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your method signature and use Async method like :

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    await db.SaveUsernameAsync(txtUsername.Text);
    new Form2().Show();
}


class Database
{
    public async Task  SaveUsername(string username)
    {
        Connect(); //Connection to database
        //Some lines to save username in database
        ....
        await db.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

**OR save User in a new thread:**

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    await Task.Run(() => SaveUsername(txtUsername.Text));    
    new Form2().Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can I ask what does `await` do in this circumstance?

Comment: And how is `await db.SaveAsync();` going to help in `SaveUsername` function? `db.` object is not in function

Comment: long stroy short it`does not block the thread on which it is executing and continue executing the rest of the method`, find out more about await [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await)

Comment: this is not criticizing but wondering myself and hoping that you can explain: why choose to make everything even the GUI async(the buton event) above the use of a line like: `new Thread(db.SaveUsername)`

Comment: The Task.Run() is OK, as long as the Db use is thread-safe. But the `await`s should go here, they serve no purpose. With them, the user will probably still see the delay.

Comment: I am getting this Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Comment: @Alen, every method with an `await` should have `async` between the public/private and return value, also the return value should be `void`, `Task` or `Task<returnType>`

Comment: Yesss, fixed it with void. But I still didnot understand this line `await db.SaveAsync();` in SaveUsername function

Comment: @Alen `db.SaveAsync()` is just a pseudo code and example of your save method, you can replace it with your actual db save method, as @dragOnvil mentioned if it's not async you can't call it with `await` keyword

Comment: Got it. rather than this I wrote queries and ExecuteNonQuery methods

Comment: An event handler (btn_Click) is one of the rare cases where you can (should) use `async void`. Does `async Task` even compile, on the += statement?

Answer (score 3):

You could implement `async` and `await` as denoted, with a fairly simple example.  However, that code will allow your application to work and free a thread, to avoid locking your User Interface or other aspects.

However, the code does have drawbacks or may offer no benefits in some cases.  So use the asynchronous capabilities wisely.  However, you should be aware that even by freeing your application and maybe creating separate threads to access your database, SQL Server will prioritize and perform said actions the way configured.

So certain actions your application does, may be hindered if you have large database traffic.  So keep in mind that.  SQL will thread the request how it believes will ensure data integrity.